# What does $\lVert\mu \rVert=1$ mean for a measure $\mu$ on a compact metric space?

Tags: measure-theory

What does $\lVert\mu \rVert=1$ mean for a measure $\mu$ on a compact metric space $\Omega$?

Sorry, I would like to add some own ideas, but I do not have... it has to be a kind of normalization on length 1, but I have no idea what that means.

Has this something to do with $\mu$ having a compact support?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a **nonnegative** measure, this simply means $\mu(X)=1$. Otherwise, see Definition 1.4 here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_in_measure_theory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be defined in the paper/book where you've seen it, but my guess would be that it's the total variation of a measure, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_of_a_measure

If $\mu$ is positive then it's just $\mu(\Omega)$, if it's a signed measure then you probably know that you can decompose it into positive and negative parts (Jordan decomposition) $\mu_+$ and $\mu_{-}$ - then you just take $||\mu|| = \mu_+(\Omega) + \mu_-(\Omega)$